# PropTypes validators directly is not supported from `TreeView`, `ObjectInspector`, `ConnectedTreeNode`, `ObjectRootLabel`, `ObjectPreview`

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this `PropTypes validators directly is not supported` warning for these components `TreeView`, `ObjectInspector`, `ConnectedTreeNode`, `ObjectRootLabel`, `ObjectPreview`, but I don't know what library these components belong to.

How can I get rid of these warnings?

```
Warning: Failed Context Types: Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by the `prop-types` package. Use `PropTypes.checkPropTypes()` to call them. Check the render method of `TreeView`.
Warning: Failed Context Types: Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by the `prop-types` package. Use `PropTypes.checkPropTypes()` to call them. Check the render method of `ObjectInspector`.
Warning: Failed Context Types: Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by the `prop-types` package. Use `PropTypes.checkPropTypes()` to call them. Check the render method of `ConnectedTreeNode`.
Warning: Failed Context Types: Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by the `prop-types` package. Use `PropTypes.checkPropTypes()` to call them. Check the render method of `ObjectRootLabel`.
Warning: Failed Context Types: Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by the `prop-types` package. Use `PropTypes.checkPropTypes()` to call them. Check the render method of `ObjectPreview`.
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Even I got the same issue but both react and prop-types package was up to date.

I had written

```
visibility: PropTypes.bool()
```

instead of

```
visibility: PropTypes.bool
```

I was using the PropTypes type as functions so it was throwing the error.

Comment: We had `PropTypes.func` used on `defaultProps` if helps anyone to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use search in your project files to find the libraries in which these components are located. Here are some I found using Google Search:

- `TreeView` - [`react-treeview`](https://github.com/chenglou/react-treeview)
- `ObjectInspector` - [`react-object-inspector`](https://github.com/xyc/react-object-inspector)
- `ObjectRootLabel` - [`react-inspector`](https://github.com/xyc/react-inspector)

Try to download the last versions of these libraries to see if they fix these warnings. If not, you can create a PR/issue or just wait when someone will fix it.

Btw, in [production build](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#use-the-production-build) of your React app these warnings will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this errors because a component library that is using prop-types package has been updated, but your version of React is not compatible with it, you will have to update `React` to version `15.3.0` or to latest version. check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types#compatibility) for more info